# Right approach writing a Dockerfile with Node as backend

Tags: node.js, angular, docker, npm

I am writing a simple angular app which uses node as back-end for file upload. My project folder is as such:

[image]

To run this in Angular, I do

1. ng serve
2. Simultaneously run "nodemon server" in another command line in same folder and I am good to go. I tried doing this in Dockerfile with below instructions:

```
#Getting Base Image
FROM node:latest AS builder

#CMD ["echo", "Docker Image for eOTA Index Page!"]

WORKDIR /app

ENV PATH /app/node_modules/.bin:$PATH


#add app
COPY . /app

#install and app dependencies

COPY server.js /app/server.js

COPY package.json /app/package.json

RUN npm install

RUN npm install -g @angular/cli

#RUN npm install rxjs-compat --save

RUN npm install rxjs

#RUN npm install bootstrap --save

RUN npm install bootstrap

#RUN npm install ng2-file-upload --save

RUN npm install ng2-file-upload

RUN npm install -g @angular/material

#RUN npm install express multer body-parser dotenv --save

RUN npm install express multer body-parser dotenv

#RUN npm install nodemon --save-dev

RUN npm install -g nodemon

RUN npm run build --prod

#RUN npm nodemon server

CMD ["nodemon", "/app/server.js"]

FROM nginx:latest

COPY --from=builder /app/dist/ng8fileupload /usr/share/nginx/html
```

I am able to run the angular project however can never run server.js. App upload breaks. If i try running nodemon server via command line everything works. What am I doing wrong while running nodmon?

Comment: The backend service would need to run in a separate container.  The contents of a Docker image are fixed once you build it; you should be able to set `CMD ["node", "/app/server.js"]` without installing nodemon or similar development-only tools.

Comment: So do you mean i make a separate image for server.js and run it ?

Comment: When you ran the backend code locally did u build it with  npm run build --prod or npm run build?

Comment: Also try running the backend container separately i.e. remove the frontend dependencies. Share the container logs for any errors

Comment: Thanks @iAviator I ll try to run as two separate containers and get back.

Comment: Ran two separate containers and node server is running also but still wont work with frontend. Any pointers @iAviator

Comment: I would suggest you to use Docker compose.Check my answer and the example link in that which has separate containers for UI, backend and database.Im not sure how your frontend uses the backend and what error exactly you are facing, but the appropriate approach would be the one I answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you to modularize your code into frontend and backend components.
So, your backend code will live in the backend folder and frontend code will live in the frontend folder.
There will be separate Dockerfile for each in frontend and backend folder.
Now, to assemble the containers use Docker compose file which will live in root directory of your project.
Check the example here https://github.com/wkrzywiec/kanban-board/blob/master/docker-compose.yml

Comment: Running both the frontend and backend via yml file solved the actual problem of linking both the containers.